# 18.04 sees both Titan RTX GPUs. Why does only one monitor display?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

**Short version:**

Why is my second monitor, via a HDMI on the secondary GPU not displaying?

Primary GPU is in the primary PCI slot, secondary is in secondary slot connected with **NVLINK bridge**.

Second monitor and HDMI work on Win10.

**Long version:**

```
nvidia-smi --query-gpu=name --format=csv,noheader
```

Shows **both** GPUs are **recognized**:

```
TITAN RTX
TITAN RTX
```

More verbosely, `nvidia-smi` shows:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.33.01    Driver Version: 440.33.01    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  TITAN RTX           On   | 00000000:17:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 41%   50C    P0    63W / 280W |     12MiB / 24220MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  TITAN RTX           On   | 00000000:65:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 41%   60C    P2    79W / 280W |    867MiB / 24217MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    1      1502      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            18MiB |
|    1      1599      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          50MiB |
|    1      1906      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           329MiB |
|    1      2052      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         238MiB |
|    1      3361      G   gnome-control-center                           3MiB |
|    1      3463      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                      14MiB |
|    1      4014      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       3MiB |
|    1      4054      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       3MiB |
|    1     29040      G   ...uest-channel-token=11987938483811999570    32MiB |
|    1     31232      C   /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin     165MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The **NVIDIA** drivers are **installed**, both via [NVIDIA's website](https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/141512/en-us), and via the Software & Updates (NVIDIA-driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-440).

But when I plug the second HDMI+monitor into the secondary Titan (which is bridged with an NVLINK), why does it not display?

**I have tried**

1. Tested the second monitor on a laptop running **Win10** and it **does** detect and extend the display. So the issue is not a broken cable/screen/etc.
2. Not much else.

**Background**

We are setting up a GPU Rig, I am the lab's new Computational Biologist / Data Architect / Sys. admin guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Solved**

The bottom line is that out of the **2+ GPU**s you have:

[image]

Only the **primary card** is responsible for **monitor displays**:

[image]

So you need to connect **both monitors to the primary card**. And they work!

---

### Background

Got in contact with NVIDIA's support chat: https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/chat/chat_launch

After a lengthy back and forth, this amounted to email correspondence directly with a Titan RTX expert.

---

## You may then ask: is my secondary card doing nothing?

**For Deep learning:**

It certainly contributes massively, for massively parallelizable problems such as deep learning.

We've been working with PyTorch and having **48GB of DDR6 VRAM** (2 x 24GB Titan RTX cards) and 1**42 parallel workers** (2 x 72 x Titan RTX cards) is being fully utilised (check this via `nvidia-smi`): as long as you have the NVLink bridge connecting them.

**For Gaming & other things:**

Not tested this.